# .net weakreferenc is empty

Tags: c#, .net, weak-references

WeakReference TryGetTarget not working reliably

I pass a  reference to a method in one form to a second form.  The second form encapsulates this method in a weak reference to prevent memory leaks, but the code itself stays in memory for the application life time.
The second form creates a background worker which then immediately executes the code of this method.
However, when trying to get a reference to the code of the method using WeakReference TryGetTarget(), about 1 out of 10 times, the method returns false and the target is unavailable.  This happens even while the code stays in memory for the application life time.

This happens in a large complicated application.  The behavior is not reproducible in a simple example, but for reference I attach a simple example to show the structure of the problem.

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
 {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var f2 = new Form2(this);
        f2.ShowDialog();
    }
}

public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private readonly WeakReference<Form> _fWeakReference;

    private Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Shown += OnShown;
    }

    private void OnShown(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        var backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
        backgroundWorker.DoWork += BackgroundWorkerOnDoWork;
        backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void BackgroundWorkerOnDoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs doWorkEventArgs)
    {
         Form target;
         if (!_fWeakReference.TryGetTarget(out target))
             throw new Exception("WeakReference is empty");
    }

    public Form2(Form form):this()
    {

       _fWeakReference = new WeakReference<Form>(form);
    }

    protected override bool ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
    {
        if (ModifierKeys == Keys.None && keyData == Keys.Escape)
        {
            Close();

        }

        return base.ProcessDialogKey(keyData);
    }
}
```

Comment: On the basis that [`select` is not broken](https://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/tips), by far the most likely explanation of the behavior you're seeing is that whatever the `WeakReference` is referring to **has** been reclaimed and is no longer in memory (even though you think it is). Your best bet is probably to focus your debugging on that.

Comment: I don't think I would ever use a WeakReference to handle a memory leak. With a weakreference you simply allow that reference to become null and you need to handle it accordingly when it does (fail, recreate a new instance, other magic). Isn't the real issue that your Form1 creates instances of types that implement IDisposable but you don't call Dispose on any of them?

Comment: Could you try to reduce your sample only to relevant code? Or even better could you try to create sample that could actually be used to reproduce your problem?

Comment: the problem is this is not reproduce outside of production , in this sample it works as it should. the purpose of this post is to find maybe same  experience of other people.

Comment: This question would benefit from some consistent wording... you talk about *reference to a method* and *code stays in memory*, but all your example code shows is passing around a reference to the the `Form1` instance.

Comment: A hint for making the example better reproducable: Call `GC.Collect();` inside `BackgroundWorkerOnDoWork` right before `_fWeakReference.TryGetTarget`, then it should fail every single time for an existing reference problem instead of 1 out of 10. This will also allow you to create a lot simpler examples where the missing reference doesn't depend on a bulk of other things happening in between.

Comment: this code should never fail. what we experience in hour production is moor complex code end environment. the question is , is there any reason that   when you put reference in wearkreference and you access it from other thread ( it is what happens hear)  target is empty ? (the reference is not garbig collected it is there fore shure)